# BunsenLabs (Debian derrivative) won't shut down (Failed to start poweroff.target: Transaction is destructive)

Tags: systemd, udev, shutdown, bunsenlabs

I stumbled upon a weird behaviour of my BunsenLabs GNU/Linux (which is based on Debian).

Sometimes I cannot turn off the OS. I doesn't matter whether I use `sudo poweroff` or the GUI approach.

This is what I get after running `sudo poweroff`:

> ```
> Failed to start poweroff.target: Transaction is destructive
> ```

Is there a workaround? Why is it happening?

---

Here is the content of my `/lib/udev/rules.d/70-power-switch.rules`:

```
ACTION=="remove", GOTO="power_switch_end"

SUBSYSTEM=="input", KERNEL=="event*", SUBSYSTEMS=="acpi", TAG+="power-switch"
SUBSYSTEM=="input", KERNEL=="event*", KERNELS=="thinkpad_acpi", TAG+="power-switch"

LABEL="power_switch_end"
```

Comment: The configuration file is Ok, Maybe you get the best answer by searching.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've been ducking for the solution for a while and finally I've found a solution. It worked for me. I don't know what triggers this weird behaviour though.

This is the recipe for shutting down your Debian:

1. Run `ps aux | grep suspend`.
2. One of the results should be looking like this

   > ```
   > root 3651 0.0 0.0 8668 1716 ? Ss 07:18 0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-sleep suspend
   > ```
3. Run `sudo kill 3651` or whatever the pid of your result is.
4. At the first time, I was able to shutdown the PC. The second time the PC went to sleep immediately after the `kill` command.

It is suggested that you log out of the graphical desktop environment before killing the process.

Source: [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2310187).

Answer (score 6):

I am adding another answer to this question, because in my case there was no `systemd-sleep` process running, yet I could not halt, shutdown, poweroff, nor reboot my machine. (I think this behaviour is once more proof that `systemd` fully qualifies as a [malware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malware), but let's leave that discussion for another time.)

In the end, I resorted to the kernel for help in my struggle against `systemd`. The following is not so different from a hard-reboot (pushing the power button), but can help, in case you don't have physical access to the machine:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

Once rebooted, [proceed](http://without-systemd.org/) by [wiping out](http://systemd-free.org/) the spawn of hell.

Comment: This is really the last resort option. Avoid if you have a database running or good chances of data corruption. You really want to sync the system's IO buffers before rebooting with `echo b` like this: `echo s > /proc/sysrq-trigger` (and wait for some time). Then, maybe try to umount all filesystems with `echo u` (careful, this one I don't know if it could make you lose your remote connection to the machine).

Comment: @Totor you are right... in the end I found myself writing a script that does all you mentioned, plus shutting down some service. That's when I realised that basically systemd forced me to write my own init script to shutdown! Welcome to 2016...

Answer (score 1):

Had this same issue.

```
# systemctl status poweroff.target 
● poweroff.target - Power-Off
  Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/poweroff.target; enabled; vendor preset: 
  Active: inactive (dead)
    Docs: man:systemd.special(7)
```

I then ran, **systemctl start poweroff.target**

And it shut down.

Comment: not working for me: "Failed to start poweroff.target: Transaction is destructive."